# How to ensure code does not throw null pointer exception went not defining property in Request Body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, service, endpoint

I am developing a spring boot API that is able to extract a users Steam Game Statistics, Battle Net Game Statistics and a variety of other game statistics, by calling a service called gamesServiceAPI

Here is the logic for the service method that extracts the users game statistics data.

```
public void preload(User user) throws IOException, SteamApiException {
    if(!user.getBattlenet().equals(""))
    {
        loader.loadCallOfDuty(user);
    }
    if(!user.getPubGPlayerName().equals("") && user.getPubGPlayerName() != null)
    {
       loader.loadPUBG(user);
    }
    if(!user.getRunescapeDisplayName().equals("") && user.getRunescapeDisplayName() != null) {
        loader.loadRunescape(user);
    }

    if(!user.getSteamId().equals("") && user.getSteamId() != null)
    {
       if(APIFetcher.resolveCSGO(user.getSteamId()))
        {
            loader.loadCSGO(user);
        }
        if(APIFetcher.resolveTeamFortressTwo(user.getSteamId()))
        {
            loader.loadTeamFortress2(user);
        }
        //Else do nothing, since they dont play the games we cover.
    }

}
```

Now not all users will play all the games in our service some may play runescape, while not play the other games.

Now when I pass a request  from POSTMAN that hits the end point and calls this method

```
{
"username": "Steven R",
"password": "hi12345",
 "steamId": "76561198882328170",
"pubGPlayerName": "YYpD_33510888",
"runescapeDisplayName": "DrumGun"
}
```

I have not specified my Battle Net ID, this throws a null pointer exception in the if statement, how do i mitigate this, since the user does not play games on the battle net platform

Answer (score 0):

Usually people reverse `equals`-checks to use the *constant* part of the check as the first part on which the possibly-non-constant part is called to avoid said possible `NullPointerException`s, similar to

`!("".equals(user.getBattlenet()))`